# Serve HTML as a Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, or Forms user interface doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying the example presented by Google for adding a menu item that displays a dialog in a Google spreadsheet found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/  Upon selecting 'Open' from the added menu, the dialog comes up but only displays the title.  The 'Hello World' and button do not display.  Is their code outdated or ???

Here's a link to a spreadsheet with the example code.  Doesn't work for me.  Dialog comes up with only the title. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hYMQIlvV39iXHXYkkHanu4bL5p9F0aF7Up-F7oRoHLE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Post code used and post screenshots. It's not outdated.

Comment: Cut and pasted code into a test sheet and it works for me.

Comment: Example link added to original comment.

Comment: Your code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Cooper.  It turns out it was a browser extension causing the issue.